# In what order does GNU env print environment variables?

Tags: linux, command-line, environment-variables, gnu, coreutils

When invoked without arguments, the `env` and `printenv` commands from the GNU Coreutils print the value of every environment variable.  What determines the order in which these variables are printed?  It's not alphabetical order, nor is it the order in which the variables were set.

Answer (score 5):

Each process has a list of strings which it maintains as its environment.  When you add, modify or delete items from this list, the runtime library has to update the corresponding array.  Because there is no standard requirement for maintaining that in sorted form, the runtime uses what the developers decided was the quickest way to update the list.  Performance considerations are what **determine** the order.

For more information of course, the [source code of `env`](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/coreutils.git/tree/src/env.c) is available for inspection.  It prints the environment in the order that the array `environ` uses.